# How to deal with "Landing Pages" in a JSF 2.2 application by using protected-views

Tags: csrf, jsf-2.2, csrf-protection, owasp

Is there a way to declare landing pages in a JSF 2.2 application. The OWASP CSRF-Gurad_3 provides a landing page token for that purpose which handles requests with missing CSRF prevention tokens as below.

> [..] All query-string or form parameters sent with the original request will be discarded. If this property is not defined, CSRFGuard will instead auto-post the user to the original context and servlet path. The following configuration snippet instructs OWASP CSRFGuard to redirect the user to /Owasp.CsrfGuard.Test/index.html when the user visits a protected resource without having a corresponding CSRF token present in the HttpSession object [..]

Here's the [link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFGuard_3_Configuration) to the article.

Comment: You mean a `<welcome-page>`?

Comment: @kolossus No, I mean pages whose links are allowed to be shared among other web-sites. The problem here is that for those embedded links there aren't any synchronizer tokens available. Hence clicking on such a link will be recognized as a CSRF attack, because of the missing token. There must be a way to declare such pages as a "Landing Page".

Comment: @My-Name-Is Did you ever get a solution to this?

Comment: @emeraldjava, no i never got an answer on that topic. But i think that this question is obsolete, since JSF provides a ViewState which acts (although it was introduced to support the browsers back button) as a CSRF-Token.  If you decide to keep the ViewState at client side then you definitely should encrypt it properly.